# How to find the average values of the two adjacent values?

Tags: python, average

I would like to calculate the average values of the two adjacent values. That means the array below its shape is (6,6). I hope to make its shape will be (6,3).
For example, I want to get the average value [0,0] term (1) and [0,1] term (2), and then get the average of [0,2] term (45) and [0,3] term (32) using for loop...

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 45, 32, 9],
              [5, 23, 5, 23, 42, 5],
              [7, 34, 3, 53, 60, 12],
              [324, 135, 323, 76, 1, 51],
              [89, 573, 65, 213, 23, 8],
              [231, 53, 84, 17, 31, 1]])
```

Comment: Why do you want to use for loops, when numpy allows faster vectorized operations?

Comment: Can you provide expected output, at least for row 1?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a `for` loop, just reshape the array, and use standard NumPy functions:

```
n_rows = a.shape[0]
print(a.reshape(-1, 2).mean(axis=1).reshape(n_rows, -1))

// [[  1.5  24.   20.5]
// [ 14.   14.   23.5]
// [ 20.5  28.   36. ]
// [229.5 199.5  26. ]
// [331.  139.   15.5]
// [142.   50.5  16. ]]
```

To understand the intuition behind program, observe each separate step:

1. Group values by 2, (it relies on the fact, that number of columns in the array is *even*)

```
print(a.reshape(-1, 2))

[[  1   2]
 [  3  45]
 [ 32   9]
 [  5  23]
 [  5  23]
 [ 42   5]
 [  7  34]
 [  3  53]
 [ 60  12]
 [324 135]
 [323  76]
 [  1  51]
 [ 89 573]
 [ 65 213]
 [ 23   8]
 [231  53]
 [ 84  17]
 [ 31   1]]
```

2. Compute averages over columns of the reshaped array (i.e. over pairs of numbers)

```
print(a.reshape(-1, 2).mean(axis=1))

[  1.5  24.   20.5  14.   14.   23.5  20.5  28.   36.  229.5 199.5  26.
 331.  139.   15.5 142.   50.5  16. ]
```

3. We have a one-dimensional array - reshape it back to the same number of rows

```
print(a.reshape(-1, 2).mean(axis=1).reshape(n_rows, -1))

[[  1.5  24.   20.5]
 [ 14.   14.   23.5]
 [ 20.5  28.   36. ]
 [229.5 199.5  26. ]
 [331.  139.   15.5]
 [142.   50.5  16. ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
averages = [[((row[i] + row[i+1]) / 2) for i in range(0, 5, 2)] for row in a]
```

Output:

```
[[1.5, 24.0, 20.5], 
[14.0, 14.0, 23.5], 
[20.5, 28.0, 36.0], 
[229.5, 199.5, 26.0], 
[331.0, 139.0, 15.5], 
[142.0, 50.5, 16.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

1. create an empty array with same number of rows as `a` but half the number of columns.
2. Loop through columns of this new array
3. Each column in the new array is average of 2 adjacent columns of array `a`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 45, 32, 9],
              [5, 23, 5, 23, 42, 5],
              [7, 34, 3, 53, 60, 12],
              [324, 135, 323, 76, 1, 51],
              [89, 573, 65, 213, 23, 8],
              [231, 53, 84, 17, 31, 1]])


def avg_of_adj(a):
    avg_array = np.empty(shape=(a.shape[0],int(a.shape[1]/2)))
    for i in range(avg_array.shape[1]):
        avg_array[:,i] = (a[:,2*i] + a[:,2*i+1])/2
    return avg_array

print(avg_of_adj(a))
```

Output:

```
[[  1.5  24.   20.5]
 [ 14.   14.   23.5]
 [ 20.5  28.   36. ]
 [229.5 199.5  26. ]
 [331.  139.   15.5]
 [142.   50.5  16. ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As comments suggest and from j1-lee suggests, there are faster ways, but one way to use for loops is:

```
import numpy as np

ll= [[1, 2, 3, 45, 32, 9],
    [5, 23, 5, 23, 42, 5],
    [7, 34, 3, 53, 60, 12],
    [324, 135, 323, 76, 1, 51],
    [89, 573, 65, 213, 23, 8],
    [231, 53, 84, 17, 31, 1]]

def get_avg(l):
    ret = []
    for i in range(0, len(l),2):
        ret.append((l[i]+ l[i+1])/2)
    return ret

avg_ll = [get_avg(l) for l in ll]

final = np.array(avg_ll)

print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I know what you're asking.  Here's code that produces three rows, where each row is the average of a pair of rows:

```
>>> b = (a[0::2,:] + a[1::2]) / 2
>>> print(b)
[[  3.   12.5   4.   34.   37.    7. ]
 [165.5  84.5 163.   64.5  30.5  31.5]
 [160.  313.   74.5 115.   27.    4.5]]
```

Comment: It's actually required to get a `(6, 3)` array, you've got it `(3, 6)`